Scanning a list according to the elements in the list (Python)
This is a homework question, I've tried several ways to solve, but I haven't been able to make progress in, and I would appreciate any tips, and help in general.
The question: we are given a list of non-negative integers. The objective is to scan the elements of the list according to the number in the current cell (i.e: the list [2,2,3,2,0] will scanned as follows: 2 -> 3 -> 2 -> 3 -> 2..., and the list [3,0,1,4,2] will be scanned as follows: 3 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1 -> 0).
The scan starts at index 0, and ends when we reach a cell containing 0.
The goal is to detect lists such as the second example (last index 0, and scanning all the elements of the list).
I tried working with a "for" loop going over the elements of the given list, and saving the value in a parameter called "index", and changing the value of a scanned item in the list. However the loop would go according to the sequence in the list, and not according to the "new" type of scan I tried creating. For example, here is what I last wrote:
def is_perfect(lst):
    '''
    :param lst:
    :return:
    '''
    next_index = 0
    lst_idx = [0]
    for val in lst:
        if val > len(lst):
            raise IndexError
        else:
            lst_idx.append(lst[next_index])
            next_index = val
            if len(lst_idx) <= len(lst):
                continue
            else:
                return False


Do you have a question? You didn't ask any.

Why are you raising IndexError? The task description doesn't say that.

My question is how to scan across the list, when the indices, according to which I am progressing, are the integers making up the list. The reason for IndexError is if I have a list of 5 elements, one of which is a number greater than 5, I don't have this index in my list (i.e, list = [0,1,4], then list[4] does not exist)

Doesn't explain why you raise an error. I'd instead expect the function to return False.

As commented, you can use while loops. We are assuming that this is not a circular list:
def is_perfect(lst):
    vis, curr_index = set(), 0
    while 0 <= curr_index < len(lst):
        if curr_index in vis:
            return False

        vis.add(curr_index)

        if not lst[curr_index]:
            break

        curr_index = lst[curr_index]

    return len(vis) == len(lst) and lst[curr_index] == 0


print(is_perfect([2, 2, 3, 2, 0]))
print(is_perfect([3, 0, 1, 4, 2]))
print(is_perfect([1, 0]))


Results
False
True
True

Details

vis: We use an empty set() to store visited indices. This is important missing part from your approach.
curr_index: Starts at 0, representing the current index position.
The while loop iterates while the curr_index is within the valid range of lst (i.e., 0 <= curr_index < len(lst)).
If the curr_index has been visited already, the sequence has a cycle, which should return False.
Otherwise, we add curr_index to the vis set and update the curr_index to the value at the current index (lst[curr_index]).
The while loop exits if it encounters a 0 or goes out of bounds.
If our list traversal covers all the list indices (len(vis) == len(lst)) and stops at a 0 (lst[curr_index] == 0), the sequence is "perfect" and returns True, otherwise it returns False.


Thank you for the answer, however the value for the second list should be True since we scan all the cells in the list, and the last index is zero

Thank you for your help!!
Could you please just tell me the general line of thought behind your solution? Because I was really stuck on this for a good couple of days with no breakthrough...

@Daniel No problem. I added some details. Similar questions.

Use a set to note which indices have alreay been visited. Visiting an index more than once would lead to an infinite loop.
The problem statement indicates that the list will not contain negative numbers - so no need to test for that. However, it does not say that all values are guaranteed to be in range - i.e., that all values will be less than the length of the list. So a sanity check should be employed.
Thereafter, it's straightforward:
def is_perfect(lst: list[int]) -> bool:
    visited = {0}
    current_index = 0
    # test current_index against the length of the list in case of rogue values
    # if you know that all indices are viable then it's just *while True*:
    # no need to test against -ve values as that's not possible according to the problem statement
    while current_index < len(lst):
        if (current_index := lst[current_index]) == 0:
            return len(visited) == len(lst)
        # if we've already visited this index then the list is imperfect
        if current_index in visited:
            break
        visited.add(current_index)
    return False

print(is_perfect([2,2,3,2,0]))
print(is_perfect([3,0,1,4,2]))

Output:
False
True

Edit:
Having re-read the problem statement, it is apparent that we should only return True if all elements have been visited. Code amended accordingly.
